# Can't figure out why the API I'm trying to use doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
let upc = barcode;

let appKey = (insert appKey)
let appId = (insert appId)

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/item?x-app-id=" + appId + "&x-app-key=" + appKey + "&upc=" + upc,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data) {
              var foodData = data.responseJSON.foods[0];
```

We are trying to use this API for a project, but every time we try to run it, JavaScript says it that it "cannot read property '0' of undefined". We haven't run out of calls, because we got a brand new id and key. It still does not work and presents us with the same error.

Comment: You'll have to use the browser developer tools to check what is actually being returned from the HTTP request.

Comment: Could you do `console.log(data.responseJSON)`? most likely it doesn't have `foods` property.

Comment: When I go to the link in a browser, it says recourse not found. This has occurred with every new link that we get. We checked to see if the API servers are down, but they aren't. That means we must be messing something up in the code.

Comment: This is very specific to the API you are calling. Maybe you should refer to their support rather than SO. As @DipenShah said, you `data.responseJSON.foods` is `undefined`. So either you are using it in the wrong way, either you should check their documentation, and if the result you get does not match, check with their support to understand why.

Comment: We found the problem. It had to do with us using 2 API. One of them is a UPC API and the other is a food database API. The problem is that the UPC API has a lot more items than the food database API. And when we input something that the food API doesn't have, it comes back as undefined.